# Python read n line of a file with zipfile.ZipFile

Tags: python, readline, python-zipfile

I would like to know if it's possible to read the second line of each files contains in a zip file?

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(myzip.zip)
for f in zf.namelist():
   csv_f = zf.read(f)
   first_line = csv_f.split('\n', 2)[0] ...?
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Sure, it’s certainly possible.  What about the logic or steps to be taken is unclear?  Read the file; read the first line, do nothing, read the second line, do stuff. Please clarify the question as to your *specific* issue.

Comment: i need to read the second line of each csv inside zip, to extract some variables, and then read the csv with pandas with skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Like this:

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile("myzip.zip") as z:
    for n in z.namelist():
        with z.open(n) as f:
            for i in range(2):
                second_line = next(f)
```

This will only read the first two lines without reading the whole file, based on the recommendation by @S3DEV. One could be more fancy about not writing the first line to a variable `second_line`, but since it is overwritten on the second pass, this doesn't seem **to** clever.

Comment: This will read the entire file into memory.  Could be improved (made more efficient) by using the file handle `f` as an iterator and either skip the first line or `seek` to the second.

Comment: True. Modified.

Comment: perfect, many thanks!